# Editing verts via script like in editmode: scale, rotate

Tags: python, scripting, edit-mode

How do I scale or rotate the selected verts of a mesh using blender python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Relevant sections of the api documentation:

- [bmesh](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bmesh.html?highlight=bmesh.from_edit_mesh)
- [bmesh.ops](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bmesh.ops.html#module-bmesh.ops)
- [mathutils](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/mathutils.html)

---

```
# See Text Editor -> Templates -> Python -> Simple Bmesh Editmode
# This example assumes we have a mesh object in edit-mode

import bpy
import bmesh
import math
import mathutils

# Get the active mesh
obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data


# Get a BMesh representation
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
face = bm.faces.active


# Modify the BMesh, can do anything here...

# Rotate - (global)
center = bpy.context.scene.cursor_location
rot = mathutils.Euler((math.radians(45), 0.0, 0.0)).to_matrix()
bmesh.ops.rotate(
            bm,
            cent=bpy.context.scene.cursor_location,
            matrix=rot,
            verts=face.verts,
            space=obj.matrix_world
            )

# Scale - (local) - no space matrix passed
scale = mathutils.Vector((2.0, 1.0, 1.0))
bmesh.ops.scale(
            bm,
            vec=scale,
            verts=face.verts
            )

# Show the updates in the viewport
# and recalculate n-gon tessellation.
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can rotate the selected face along his local axis and not around the cursor?