# Is object data, as accessed by Python, not committed until you exit edit mode?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, vertices

I am trying to understand accessing object data from Python, in particular vertex data. In this simple test:

- Make a new Blender document
- In the scripting interface, make a function to display vertex information (as suggested [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/how-do-you-save-vertices-coordinates-in-a-list/507115)):

  ```python
  def showvertices():
    for item in bpy.data.objects:
      print(item.name)
      if item.type == 'MESH':
        for vertex in item.data.vertices:
          print(vertex.co)
  ```
- Now, typing in `showvertices()` in the Python console seems to display the correct  information for the default cube:

  ```
  Camera
  Cube
  <Vector (-1.0000, -1.0000, -1.0000)>
  <Vector (-1.0000, -1.0000, 1.0000)>
  <Vector (-1.0000, 1.0000, -1.0000)>
  <Vector (-1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000)>
  <Vector (1.0000, -1.0000, -1.0000)>
  <Vector (1.0000, -1.0000, 1.0000)>
  <Vector (1.0000, 1.0000, -1.0000)>
  <Vector (1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000)>
  Light
  ```

---

So far, so good. Now type:

- Tab -> enter edit mode
- A -> select all
- GX2 (Enter) -> move all vertices 2 units in the X direction

This appears to work, the cube moves to the right (from the front view) and the X coordinate of the top-right vertex is shown as 3m instead of 1m as it was before:

[image: Cube after moving]

**However**, typing in `showvertices()` in the Python console still displays the original information, not the updated positions:

```
Camera
Cube
<Vector (-1.0000, -1.0000, -1.0000)>
<Vector (-1.0000, -1.0000, 1.0000)>
<Vector (-1.0000, 1.0000, -1.0000)>
<Vector (-1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000)>
<Vector (1.0000, -1.0000, -1.0000)>
<Vector (1.0000, -1.0000, 1.0000)>
<Vector (1.0000, 1.0000, -1.0000)>
<Vector (1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000)>
Light
```

Now if I press Tab to go back to Object mode and type in `showvertices()` again in the console, the vertex information is now updated:

```
Camera
Cube
<Vector (1.0000, -1.0000, -1.0000)>
<Vector (1.0000, -1.0000, 1.0000)>
<Vector (1.0000, 1.0000, -1.0000)>
<Vector (1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000)>
<Vector (3.0000, -1.0000, -1.0000)>
<Vector (3.0000, -1.0000, 1.0000)>
<Vector (3.0000, 1.0000, -1.0000)>
<Vector (3.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000)>
Light
```

---

So my question is, why does the information reported by the Python function not show the new positions until I leave edit mode? Is there a cached copy of the vertex information, and the "real" data is not updated until exiting edit mode?

---

This was with Blender 2.80.57, however the same behaviour was observed in version 2.79.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/editing-verts-via-script-like-in-editmode-scale-rotate  and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/editing-verts-via-script-like-in-editmode-scale-rotate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to call the update_from_editmode () method of the object.
https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=update_from#bpy.types.Object.update_from_editmode

Comment: Of note: `update_from_editmode` will update the objects mesh data to match the edit mesh, this only needs to be done once when exiting edit mode. You can also use `bmesh.from_edit_edit_mesh()` to access the edit mesh while in edit mode and not have to repeatedly update the mesh data.