# Overriding Context for bpy.ops.transform.shrink_fatten

Tags: python, transforms, operator

I can't seem to get sufficient context for calling `bpy.ops.transform.shrink_flatten()` without this error:

`RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.transform.shrink_fatten.poll() failed, context is incorrect`

I've attempted to specify the active object and some area parameters (via [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58397/scaling-works-differently-in-gui-and-from-script)),

```
# attempt to set obj-to-be-resized as active obj
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj_to_resize

context = bpy.context
override = context.copy()

for area in context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        override["area"] = area
        override["space_data"] = area.spaces.active
        override["region"] = area.regions[-1] # rule of thumb r.type == 'WINDOW'
        break

bpy.ops.transform.shrink_fatten(override, value=0.02)
```

but this isn't enough to avoid the error. I'm not sure which context parameters I'm still missing. Inspecting the [source](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/transform/transform_ops.c) (line 947) gave me its [polling function](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/screen/screen_ops.c) (line 373), `ED_operator_editmesh`, which checks the `edit_object`.

However, attempting to override this parameter by supplying `override["edit_object"] = obj_to_resize` produces a seg fault:

```
# backtrace
blender(BLI_system_backtrace+0x34) [0x561503952f54]
blender(+0xb7b882) [0x561502ede882]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x37e00) [0x7f060029ce00]
blender(BLI_addtail+0xc) [0x56150391cfac]
blender(ED_region_draw_cb_activate+0x39) [0x561502f04739]
blender(initTransform+0x8d3) [0x561503040e73]
blender(+0xcfd54c) [0x56150306054c]
blender(+0xcfd5ff) [0x5615030605ff]
blender(+0xb836ba) [0x561502ee66ba]
blender(WM_operator_call_py+0x6d) [0x561502ee6fed]
blender(+0xfab340) [0x56150330e340]
/usr/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords+0x148) [0x7f0605df31c8]
/usr/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyCFunction_FastCallKeywords+0x21) [0x7f0605df3461]
/usr/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4a75) [0x7f0605e62a75]
/usr/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x2e9) [0x7f0605dac879]
/usr/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyFunction_FastCallDict+0x2fc) [0x7f0605dadadc]
/usr/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyObject_Call_Prepend+0x68) [0x7f0605dbd028]
/usr/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0x16d3ef) [0x7f0605e0b3ef]
/usr/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyObject_FastCallKeywords+0x3ac) [0x7f0605e1f2fc]
/usr/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5d35) [0x7f0605e63d35]
/usr/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyFunction_FastCallKeywords+0x10b) [0x7f0605df2a3b]
/usr/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x76d) [0x7f0605e5e76d]
/usr/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x2e9) [0x7f0605dac879]
/usr/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x44) [0x7f0605dad7a4]
/usr/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCode+0x1c) [0x7f0605dad7cc]
/usr/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(+0x2381e4) [0x7f0605ed61e4]
/usr/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0(PyRun_FileExFlags+0x9e) [0x7f0605ed76ee]
blender(+0xf95b38) [0x5615032f8b38]
blender(+0xb79be5) [0x561502edcbe5]
blender(BLI_argsParse+0xd7) [0x561503908347]
blender(main+0x2e9) [0x561502ec5a39]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0x7f0600289223]
blender(_start+0x2e) [0x561502edb33e]
```

What context am I missing? And why does attempting to override `edit_object` cause a seg fault?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot override context for  edit mode, ie set an object as the edit object without it being in edit mode.  Speculate the edit mode data is "loaded"  on toggle into edit mode, and the data updated when toggled back. [Recent and related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139101/is-object-data-as-accessed-by-python-not-committed-until-you-exit-edit-mode) This may be more relaxed in 2.8 where multiple objects can be edited simultaneously.

Comment: @batFINGER thanks! Included your comment in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@batFINGER's comment is helpful: you (probably) can't override context for edit mode. I ended up just replacing the `shrink_fatten` operator with the equivalent function, per [this](https://blenderartists.org/t/i-want-to-move-a-vertices-to-normal-directon-of-origin-vertex-by-python/601077/3):

```
def execute(self, context):

    ob = bpy.context.object
    me = ob.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

    for v in bm.verts:
        if v.select:
            v.co += v.normal * self.factor

    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True, False)
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

which was an order of magnitude easier and could be, in general, potentially the best way to replace relatively simple edit operations instead of overriding their context.